# Límite de tiempo de lectura de archivo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un programa que me lee una serie de archivos de los que tengo que sacar unos datos. Para algunos archivos me tarda mucho en compilar. Por tanto, quiero poner un límite de tiempo de compilación y, en caso de que lo supere hacer que pare y pase al siguiente archivo.

Estoy trabajando con la librería ortools.

Yo he probado lo siguiente:

```
 time = solver.WallTime()/1000    
    if time > 1800:
       break
    else:
       continue
```

Pero no me funciona.
¿Alguna idea?
Gracias :)

Comment: Para poder responder es necesario que coloques el código completo. Revisa este documento primero: [Como hacer un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con el paquete de la STL de Python `signal`. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
import time
import signal
import random

def manejador_tiempos(numero_señal, frame_de_interrupcion):
    raise OSError("Imposible leer el archivo")

def operacion(tiempo):
    print(f"El tiempo es: {tiempo}")
    time.sleep(tiempo)



def test_tiempos():
    tiempos = [2, 5, 1, 8, 0.5]
    for tiempo in tiempos:
        try:
            signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, manejador_tiempos)
            signal.alarm(3)
            operacion(tiempo)
            print("Operación completada con exito\n")
        except OSError:
            print("La operación no ha podido ser completada\n")


test_tiempos()
```

**Salida**

```
El tiempo es: 2
Operación completada con exito

El tiempo es: 5
La operación no ha podido ser completada

El tiempo es: 1
Operación completada con exito

El tiempo es: 8
La operación no ha podido ser completada

El tiempo es: 0.5
Operación completada con exito
```

Según la [documentación oficial de Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) la función `signal` necesita que se le pasen dos argumentos. El tipo de señal, que este caso será `signal.SIGALRM` y la función que lanza el error.

Esta función que lanza el error, que en nuestro ejemplo es `manejador_tiempos` necesita de dos argumentos para que `signal` la pueda utilizar, que son **el número de señal y el stack de interrupción**. Esto se puede ver en la documentación adjuntada.

> *** IMPORTANT NOTICE ***
> A signal handler function is called with two arguments:
> the first is the signal number, the second is the interrupted stack frame.

Una vez sabemos esto, he creado una función `operación` que simula un proceso con un coste de tiempo y después establezco que el tiempo máximo de operación es de tres segundos con `signal.alarm(3)`

Por último todo está englobado en un `try ... except` con el que capturo el error que he creado para que el proceso siga en caso de que se de dicho error.